# How to move value column to another column by condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
EMAIL NAME COUNTRY
```

I need to move email address to column `EMAIL` if it has wrong position like this:

```
EMAIL NAME        COUNTRY
Oleg  p@gmail.com  UA
```

I know there is `apply()` function to call custom validation function as regex.

I wonder how to iterate all columns in each rows and move colum value if it is email and was found in another column?

I think I can find emails using this:

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains("@", case=False).any(), axis=1)].values
```

The I need to get index row and value like this:

```
index_row   column_index   value
0           1               p@gmail.com
```

Then I have to concat found values to exist dataframe to the column `EMAIL`

Comment: What do you want to replace in the part where the column was found? NA?

Comment: What is your final output? You are providing intermediate outputs

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(x):
  
    for idx in range(len(x)):
        col = str(x[idx])
        # check if column value has @ character in it
        if '@' in str(col):
            return f'{idx} , {x[idx]}'
            
df['Email'] = df.apply(myfunc, axis=1)
df['index'] = df['Email'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
```

** This works only when there is only a single email column in a row.

Comment: It `axis=1` means we go througth all columns?

Comment: How to exclude calling `myfunc` if email was found in current row? Because I want to find address, birthday too. I mean myfunc2 have found email then next myfunc3 should not check column where email was found for current row

Comment: Yes. axis=1 means you are iterating through the columns

Comment: You don't have to exclude myfunc based on condition. if the email was found in the current column, the email column would still contain the email, it won't remove it.